# Float or double on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, floating-point

Can you use double or float on Blackberry?

If so, in which OS version or hardware model?

Edit: I believe the answers I get here, but then [something else must be the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964762/why-is-neither-float-nor-double-working-on-blackberry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently floating point *doesn't work* on some versions of Blackberry; see the comments.

Bow, if a J2ME device implements the CLDC 1.0 profile, the manufacturer is not required to include support for floating point arithmetic in the platform: see

> http://cmer.cis.uoguelph.ca/cs1cs3/slides.ppt

In CLDC 1.1, floating point support is mandatory.

---

In comments on other questions, you say that Blackberry is CLDC 1.1.

If your Blackberry's floating point support doesn't work and it really claims to implement CLDC 1.1, then that's either a bug in the execution platform or the build tool-chain, or a problem with the way you are *using* the tool-chain.  (I don't develop J2ME stuff, so I can't be more specific.)

Comment: Well, so you would think. But in fact, as soon as I introduce a single float variable (auto), the application no longer loads in OS 4.5, BB 8100 and 8800. (But works beautifully in OS 5 and 6.)

Comment: The link I provided in my answer includes timing analysis on an 8320, which was also 4.5. I think something else might be going wrong as float and double were both supported at that point.

Answer (score 3):

I put a post together a while back that shows a timing comparison with the different data types and different arithmetic processing on the BlackBerry. You might not be looking for this type of information, but it's interesting to see how your options compare.

http://www.blurrywords.com/2009/05/02/blackberry-java-arithmetic-comparisons.html

Comment: Nice comparisons - I knew multiplication was slower for doubles, but I didn't realize it was that much worse for division. I keep getting into weird arguments with people who ridicule my use of `float` instead of `double` - for some reason, using half as much memory and running twice as fast doesn't mean much to them.

Answer (score 2):

The only Java version that does not support floating-point types is the [CLDC configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLDC) of Java ME in Version 1.0 (they were re-added in Version 1.1). I'm not sure whether there are any Blackberry devices that only support CLDC 1.0, but I doubt it.

Comment: The 8100 supports CLDC 1.1   :-/

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant: then it should be fine, since it's only CLDC 1.0 that does not have floats.

Comment: Except something is wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964762/why-is-neither-float-nor-double-working-on-blackberry

Answer (score 1):

You can use `double` or `float` on any Blackberry OS and hardware model.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have been supported since a very long time ago.