# Neither float nor double works on Blackberry OS 4.5

Tags: blackberry, java-me, floating-point

As soon as I add a float or a double variable to my program, it stops working on BB models 8100 and 8800, both running OS 4.5.

I have a couple of newer phones with OS 5 and 6, respectively, and the same binary works just fine on those.

Why would this be?

Also, see "[Float or double on Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963479/float-or-double-on-blackberry/)" which led to this question.

When the application is started, before it really starts, it shows an error message to the effect of "modules bla blah can not verify blah". I'll update the message to the real one when I get a chance to start the broken app again.

Comment: Error message ? Some pointer of some kind, because it's working fine here, on a 8330 OS 4.5

Comment: Try looking at the event log, ALT L G L G

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float or double on Blackberry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963479/float-or-double-on-blackberry)

Comment: No, not a a duplicate. That question is answered. I believe the answer to this question will be something like; "oh, you did this thing wrong with your toolchain" or so.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using the correct version of BlackBerry JRE when building for OS 4.5? If you're using the Eclipse-plugin, you can get older JREs installed via the update-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoted error message is still "modules bla blah can not verify blah", which is kind of vague, but it sounds like you are building against a SDK that is newer than BlackBerry OS 4.5, and then trying to deploy the app to a 4.5 device.

It's possible that float and double are the first references that pull in modules that don't exist on OS 4.5, so it appears to you that they are breaking your app, when it is really a build issue.